Title: How to Display PC Content on an Android Device Using HDMI Input?
I have an Android device powered by a Qualcomm chip, and I would like to use it as a display for my computer through an HDMI connection. In other words, my computer will be the input source, and my Android device will act as the display.
Here are the details of my setup:
Android Device: Lahaina for arm64
Chipset: Qualcomm
Operating System: Android 12
HDMI Connection: The Android device has an HDMI port
My Questions:
Is it possible to configure my Android device to accept HDMI input from my PC?
Are there any specific APIs or libraries that can help with this functionality?
What software or drivers would I need on both the PC and the Android device?
Are there any examples or documentation available that can guide me through the setup process?
I have done some research and found limited information on using Android devices as HDMI displays. Any guidance, references, or examples would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

This question belongs on a different SE site, such as the Android SE

Are you want to develop an app or a custom Android ROM for presenting the PC display video data? If not your are off-topic here as this site is fir developer questions.

I am a programmer. My company needs to use an Android app on a self-developed Android device to display the computer screen transmitted by HDMI.

Displaying PC content on an Android device using HDMI input is challenging because most Android devices don't support HDMI input natively. However, you can use alternative methods like:
USB-C to HDMI Capture Card:
Use a USB-C to HDMI capture card to connect the PC's HDMI output to the Android device's USB-C port. The Android device must support USB OTG.
Wireless Methods:
Screen Mirroring Apps:
Use apps like TeamViewer, AnyDesk, or Splashtop to mirror the PC screen to the Android device.
Streaming Devices: Use devices like Chromecast or Miracast to stream PC content wirelessly to the Android device.

Thank you for the response. I wanted to clarify that my Android device supports HDMI input, and it appears that the kernel already has this implemented. I found an example code which treats the HDMI input as a camera device and uses CameraManager to open it.
However, the issue I'm facing is that the transmitted video from the PC only occupies a portion of the screen on the Android device, and I can't view the entire content.
I'm wondering if the HDMI transmitted video can be controlled on the Android side. Is there a way to adjust the display settings?
Thank you!
